# random order quiz ِDynamic

Tags: android, random

I want my program to ask random questions and have dynamic answers **But it only asks random questions and I need a dynamic answer**

> ```
> Button btn_1,btn_2;
> TextView text;
> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
> btn_1=findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
> btn_2=findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
> text=findViewById(R.id.text);
>
> int min = 1;
> int max = 3;
>
> Random r = new Random();
> int rand = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
> String[]question={"What is Name Color Sky ?",
>       "What is Name Color Night?",
>         "What is Blood Color?"
> };
>
> String[]answer={"Blue ",
>         "Black",
>         "White",
>         "Red",
>         "Green"
>         ,"Purple"
>
> };
> text.setText(question[rand]); }
> ```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JHGJ.jpg)

Comment: Instead of creating an array of `Strings`, rather create an array of an object that holds a question and an answer strings as it's members. Then ask the question randomly, on giving the answer, retrieve the answer from the object. Or, to make it 'easy', create a `Pair` that holds a question and it's answer.

Comment: For clarification, would you like the answers on offer to be different?  Would you like to guarantee that one of them is the correct answer?  Would you like the answers to be displayed as the text of the two Button objects defined at the top of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
btn_1.setText(answer[r.nextInt(6)])
btn_2.setText(answer[r.nextInt(6)])
```

This will choose 2 random colours independently.

**Edit**

To ensure that the correct answer is available, you will need to store the correct answers somewhere.  I strongly recommend making a Question class that stores the string for the question and the correct answer, but you can achieve the desired effect with just an array of the answers, e.g.:

```
Button[] answerButtons = new Button[] {btn1, btn2};
int numButtons = 2;
String[] correctAnswers = new String[] {"Blue", "Black", "Red"}; // you have a space after blue, remove it
List<String> answersDisplayed = Arrays.asList(new String[numButtons]);
int indexOfCorrectAnswer = random.nextInt(numButtons);
answersDisplayed.set(indexOfCorrectAnswer, correctAnswers[rand]); // the number used to pick the question earlier
for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++){
    if (correctAnswers[rand] == null) {
        // rand was used to pick the question, so pick the answer that goes with it
        // pick a random answer that hasn't come up yet
        String incorrectAnswer = answer[random.nextInt(6)];
        while (answersDisplayed.contains(incorrectAnswer)){
            incorrectAnswer = answer[random.nextInt(6)];
        }
        answersDisplayed.set(i, incorrectAnswer);
    }
    answerButtons[i].setText(answersDisplayed.get(i));
}
```

This will work for any number of buttons

Comment: Hi, the answers should not ask for clarifications. For that, you can ask through comments.

Comment: What I want is that when a random question is asked, the answer is randomly on the button one or button two and it must be between button one and button two.

Comment: @King_Tesla I have edited my answer to make sure the correct one is on one of the buttons and the other answer is different

Comment: I didn't use this solution and
  Your code sparked in my mind and I found the solution Thanks